# Error while compiling: ERROR: Cause: compileSdkVersion is not specified

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I wanted to compile my android studio project, somehow i ran into an error with firebase crashalytics. So I tried to fix the issue.

what I have now:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url = "https://maven.fabric.io/public" }
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

So far so good, theoretically that should be it, from what I've read online. But I get an error now, `ERROR: Cause: compileSdkVersion is not specified.` so i googled this error, but all the solutions i found online where about the `compileSdkVersion` abd the `targetSdkVersion` differ.

```
compileSdkVersion 29

buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'ch.workouttracker'
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 11
    versionName '0.7.6'
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    resConfigs "de" // And any other languages you support
}
```

so this is not the case here, what else should I try?

Comment: is compilesdkversion under `android` block?

Comment: yes android element is containg this block

Comment: Please add full `build.gradle` to investigate

Comment: It's compiling again. but I don't know why. So I can't help those comming from google

Comment: Do you have any problem to post full `build.gradle`?

Comment: I solved it, so I dont need help anymore